# How to convert a Shape to MovieClip using ActionScript 3.0 only

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

```
import flash.display.Shape;
import flash.display.Graphics;


stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, startAnim);

function startAnim(e:Event):void
{
    var shape1:Shape = new Shape();
    shape1.graphics.beginFill(0x333333,1);
    shape1.graphics.drawRect(40,50,250,125);
    shape1.graphics.endFill();

    addChild(shape1); // this will add a shape of rectangle to stage

}
```

This is a very simple function creating a rectangle shape on stage. Ok but the problem is how can I convert this **SHAPE** to **MOVIECLIP** using ActionScript only so I can add Events to the same (**shape1**).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hmmm by using a MovieClip instead of a Shape. a MovieClip also has a Graphics object.

```
import flash.display.MovieClip ; 
//import flash.display.Graphics;//not needed

//stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, startAnim); //remove enterframe

//function startAnim(e:Event):void { //no need for a handler
    var shape1:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
    shape1.graphics.beginFill(0x333333,1); 
    shape1.graphics.drawRect(40,50,250,125);     
    shape1.graphics.endFill();

    addChild(shape1); // this will add a MovieClip of rectangle to stage

    shape1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, dragShape);

    function dragShape(E:MouseEvent)
    {
        shape1.startDrag()
    }

shape1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dropShape);

    function dropShape(E:MouseEvent)
    {
        shape1.stopDrag()
    }
//} no need for that either :)
```

beware that, as such, your function is called on ENTER_FRAME = 25 or more times per second, therefore you'll create and add a clip to stage 25 or more times per second 
+ the reference is created locally, in the function, so you won't be able to access "shape1" from outside, once your object is created.

Comment: thank you... but is it possible to add event to this shape1 movieclip since I am trying to drag and drop this.

Comment: now i add some more script to this i:e                                  shape_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, dragShape);

  function dragShape(E:MouseEvent)
  {
   shape_mc.startDrag()
  }
  
 shape_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dropShape);

  function dropShape(E:MouseEvent)
  {
   shape_mc.stopDrag()
  }

Comment: but after this it is duplicating the movieclip for dragging and the orignal shape still at the same position (40 , 50). Yes I can drag the duplicate shapes anywhere i don't know wats happening

Comment: hmmm need your code to help: update your thread with what you've got so far + remember to use the code tags( text edition tools ) to make it more readable :)

Comment: that's what I was explaining to you : you're calling the function on ENTER_FRAME thus creating 25+ shape_mc per second. if you remove the line: *stage.add[...]* + your function : *function startAnim(e:Event):void {* and the last bracket, *}* your code will be executed once and everything will be fine :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can convert a Shape to a MovieClip. What you can do is to create a MovieClip class, and in the constructor generate the Shape object, and add it to the MovieClip.

```
public class Car extends MovieClip {
    private var shape1:Shape = new Shape();
    public function Car() {
        shape1.graphics.beginFill(0x333333,1);
        shape1.graphics.drawRect(40,50,250,125);
        shape1.graphics.endFill();
        addChild(shape1); // this will add a shape of rectangle to stage
    }
}
```

Shape has also events.

- activate
- added
- addedToStage
- deactivate
- enterFrame
- removed
- removedFromStage
- render

But since it doesn't extends from **InteractiveObject**, you can't handle input.